# Failed to use auth code flow with python MSAL

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I simply can't get `acquire_token_by_auth_code_flow()` from the MSAL package to work outside a flask app using the basic example giving in the MSAL documentation.

I think the problem comes from using the wrong authentication response which must be a "dict of the query string received from auth server" according to the documentation. In a flask app, I can simply use `request.args` which I'm not quite sure how to use outside of flask.

I've already tried using `requests.request` as well as `urlsplit`. The device flow is working fine as well as using the MSAL package in Java and connecting via R. So the app seems to be set up correctly.

The basic example code from the MSAL app below produces the error:

> state mismatch: XXXXXXXXXXXX vs None

(so `auth_response` is wrong).
Any thoughts?

```
import requests
import msal

CLIENT_ID = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX" # Application (client) ID of app registration
CLIENT_SECRET = "XX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX.XX~XXXXX~XXXX" # Placeholder - for use ONLY during testing.
AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX"
REDIRECT_PATH = "/getAToken"  # Used for forming an absolute URL to your redirect URI.
                              # The absolute URL must match the redirect URI you set
                              # in the app's registration in the Azure portal.
ENDPOINT = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me'  
SCOPE = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]

# Cache
cache = msal.SerializableTokenCache()

# Build msal app
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        CLIENT_ID, authority=AUTHORITY,
        client_credential=CLIENT_SECRET, token_cache=cache)

# Initiate auth code flow
session = requests.Session()
session.flow = app.initiate_auth_code_flow(scopes=SCOPE, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_PATH)

# Aquire token
result = app.acquire_token_by_auth_code_flow(auth_code_flow=session.flow, auth_response = dict(parse.parse_qsl(parse.urlsplit(REDIRECT_PATH).query)))
```

The equivalent code for the last bit from the flask app looks like this with `REDIRECT_PATH = "/getAToken"`:

```
@app.route(app_config.REDIRECT_PATH)  # Its absolute URL must match your app's redirect_uri set in AAD
def authorized():
    result = _build_msal_app(cache=cache).acquire_token_by_auth_code_flow(
        session.get("flow", {}), request.args)
    return redirect(url_for("index"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Getting a token requires few requests according to documentation. To make it possible you need to create flow and store it inside session before navigating to microsoft login page.

```
session["flow"] = _build_auth_code_flow(authority=app_config.AUTHORITY, scopes=app_config.SCOPE)
```

After navigation back to your application you should use this flow object as you did in your example

```
result = _build_msal_app(cache=cache).acquire_token_by_auth_code_flow(
        session.get("flow", {}), request.args)
```

Make sure that you didn't create it twice. In this case error will be similar, but state mismatch: XXXXXXXXXXXX vs XXXXXXXXXXXX. It may happened if you route called twice.

Comment: Hi, I know this is an old question, but could you please clarify what you mean by: `Make sure that you didn't create it twice.  In this case error will be similar but state mismatch: XXXXXX vs XXXXXX.`

I am struggling with exactly this issue ([see question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76240347/msal-and-msgraph-sdk-python-auth-code-flow-state-mismatch-xxxxxx-vs-xxxxxx)), but I can't figure out what's causing it.  What do you mean by "creating it twice"?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

*auth_response* must be a dictionary built from the *current* HTTP request query params.

If this is a desktop application you must switch to *PublicClientApplication*. You can find a sample [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/interactive_sample.py).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your first comment. What would be the current HTTP request query?                                                                                        
It's a web application. Besides it shouldn't make a difference using a confidential instead of a public client app because the auth code flow is a shared method between those two. So the error remains the same switching to public :(

Comment: @ZhuoHan if its a web app great. I don't do too much python but you need to pass the request query params. In your code case I guess it might be something similar to requests.request.query or requests.request.queryparams. The auth code flow implementation is similar but not the same for native applications since there is no need for manual code/token exchange. It was recommended in case it was not a web application. Do a fiddler trace for both the request and response to see what value is sent and returned as state.

Comment: I tried to run the sample you provided using a PublicClientApplication (set the switch in Azure as well to allow for public client flows). Unfortunately get another error which I find very odd for a PublicClientApp (should not need a client secret?):  
invalid_client
AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.

Comment: @ZhuoHan let's go back to the confidentialclient which is the proper one. can you share your code in github?