# MSAL and MSGraph SDK (Python): Auth Code Flow - State Mismatch XXXXXX vs XXXXXX

Tags: python, flask, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to use the `MSAL` library and `msgraph` SDK in Python to authorise my web application's backend (Flask) to access the MS Graph API "on behalf of" users.  The `acquire_token_by_auth_code_flow` function results in a `state mismatch: XXXXXX vs XXXXXX`, where both sides of the "mismatch" in the stack trace are identical.

For context, I'm temporarily storing the result of `initiate_auth_code_flow` in the `database`, as I need to send the `auth_uri` to the frontend (React), to open in a new tab, so I can't use `session storage` for this.

I'm using the `state` argument in `initiate_auth_code_flow` to store the `user id` so that I can identify the user upon authorisation, allowing me to retrieve the user's `auth_code_flow_data` from the database.

I'm then passing this into the `acquire_token_by_auth_code_flow` function.  Here's a minimal representation of my code (simplified):

```
### send_email.py (uses asyncio for async/await)

# Context: Sending an email on behalf of the user...

...
...

# Initialise MS Graph client
ms_graph_client = initialise_ms_graph_client(user=user, scopes=scopes)

# Send email
await ms_graph_client.me.send_mail.post(request_body)

...
...

# Return from endpoint
return {"msg": "email sent."}
```

```
### get_ms_graph_client.py

...
...

# Get user id
user_id = get_user_id()

# Get user's access token from token cache, if possible (or generate with refresh token)
access_token = get_access_token_from_cache(user=user)

# If no access token or valid refresh token...
if access_token is None:

    # Initialise state to pass to "auth code flow"
    auth_code_flow_state = {"id": user_id}

    # Initialise new MSAL client (loads user's token cache, etc.)
    msal_client = ConfidentialClientApplication(...)

    # Initialise "auth code flow"
    auth_code_flow = msal_client.initiate_auth_code_flow(scopes=scopes, 
    redirect_uri=redirect_uri, state=auth_code_flow_state)

    # Store "auth code flow data" in database
    store_in_database(json.dumps(auth_code_flow))

    # Abort request, sending "auth code flow uri" to frontend (to open in new tab)
    return abort_json(401, "auth_uri": auth_code_flow["auth_uri"])

# Initialise "on behalf of" credential
credential = OnBehalfOfCredential(user_assertion=access_token, ...)

# Initialise "auth provider"
auth_provider = AzureIdentityAuthenticationProvider(credentials=credential, scopes=scopes)

# Initialise HTTP adapter
adapter = GraphRequestAdapter(auth_provider)

# Initialise and return Graph Service Client
return GraphServiceClient(adapter)
```

```
### sign_in_route.py (Azure AD Redirect URI)

...
...

# Get state from "auth code flow"
state = request.args.get("state")

# Get user from state
user = get_user_from_state(state)

# Validate user
validate_user()

# Initialise new MSAL client (loads user's token cache, etc.)
msal_client = ConfidentialClientApplication(...)

# Get user's "auth code flow data" from database
auth_code_flow_data = json.loads(get_auth_code_flow_data_from_database(user=user))

# Get tokens from "auth code flow" -> "state mismatch: XXXXXX v XXXXXX"
result = msal_client.acquire_token_by_auth_code_flow(auth_code_flow_data, request.args)

# This is where the error occurs ^^^
...
...

# Update user's token cache
update_user_token_cache(user=user, cache=msal_client.token_cache)

# Remove user's "auth code flow data" from database
remove_from_database(auth_code_flow_data)

# Return success message
return {"msg": "authorised"}
```

If anyone has any ideas as to what's going on here, I'd be very appreciative.  I've lost a lot of time to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To get access token for on behalf of a user please check this authorization code flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?view=graph-rest-1.0#authorization-request

Comment: @MehtabSiddique, thanks for your response.  However, it's my understanding that the MSAL library handles this process behind the scenes.  It initiates the auth code flow as appropriate, but upon "signing in" on the client-side in the browser, the backend returns a "state mismatch" (yet the two cited "state" objects are identical).  Could this somehow be a result of storing the generated "auth code flow" object in the database rather than in the user session?  Any suggestions would be welcomed as I've hit a bit of a brick wall on this.  Thanks